Is there a way to use Azure AD authentication on a web app that is already setup for ASP.NET Identity?
We've got an older app that is already setup to use ASP.NET Identity. It's actually two web apps, one is for external use (customers) and one is for internal use (staff).
Currently both web apps use the same authentication. You could login to the internal web app with the same user/pass as what you log into the external web app as. You just wouldn't have permissions to access anything unless you were given them.
A few years ago we started making all of our internal web apps use Azure AD and our external web apps use Azure B2C.
For this app though, we want to keep the external web app using ASP.NET Identity but change the internal web app to use Azure AD.
The issue I'm running into is that we still need to be able to use the UserManager, SignInManager, and RoleManager that are part of the ASP.NET Identity package. We need these in order for our staff to support our customers. Which means I still need to setup ASP.NET Identity in my Startup.cs. I've added the code to use Azure AD in the Startup.cs as well, but it seems like the web app prioritizes the ASP.NET Identity auth instead of the Azure AD auth.
The web app has been upgraded to .NET 8.
In my Startup.cs I have:
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));


services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

I tried changing the order, it didn't seem to affect anything. If I remove the services.AddIdentity line then the app will properly use the Azure Ad for auth, but then all the code we have for managing users is broken.


we still need to be able to use the UserManager, SignInManager, and
RoleManager that are part of the ASP.NET Identity package

When we use Asp.net core default identity, we will have a database storing User account and Password, then we can use UserManager, SignInManager and so on to manage the user authentication and authorization. Then if we want to allow users to sign in the application with external accounts, such as Microsoft account, we will face an issue that how to connect to user1 account to the Microsoft account of user1.
Now we have an out-of-box configuration to connect to enternal authentication providers. This contains a process that when users use their Microsoft account to sign in the application, the application will also create a local user account in the database for this user.
We should have builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser> in Program.cs, then please add codes below behind this line. Follow the link I shared to get the client id and client secret. COdes below requires nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
    {
        microsoftOptions.ClientId = "client_id";
        microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "client_secret";
    });

To see more details about external account login, you could right click on the project name in VS and Add -> New Scaffolded Item -> Choose Identity in the left widget and double click the Identity in the middle widget -> then scaffold the external login page.


What if I don't want to connect the Azure AD account to an Identity account? Our staff just needs the ability to manage those Identity users. Like change email addresses for example. But the staff wouldn't actually have an Identity account.

@user27046570 I'm afraid that's not a good idea for it...Because it will require your developing team to add 2 authentication mechanism into one application, and then the app need to modify the current sign in page to add an entrance for AAD login, then they need to unify how to display user information, and many other works and it's complex. I had a sample for cookie auth + AAD, I think it's really not a good idea.

or may be you can create a new replica application only for external users to visit?
